# Consuming & exposing a REST service and passing JSON body

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am using Apache Camel with XML DSL to consume & expose a REST service.
 I have a request body `{"name":"your name","phonenumber":"111-111"}`

I am successfully able to directly send this json request body and get a successfull response from the consumed endpoint url. Whereas when I go through my exposed URL I am getting the following exception.

```
org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletOperationException: Restlet operation failed invoking 
<!--Consumed URL--> with statusCode: 400 /n responseBody:
{"timestamp":"2020-04-07T06:15:41.302+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request",
"message":"Required request body is missing: public boolean
com.agcs.cids.BookingRestController.createBooking(org.bson.Document...)","path":"-----"}
```

I am successfully even able to print the body just before I make a call to the URL. Please fine my code below:

```
<log loggingLevel="TRACE" message="Request from source: Body: ${body}" />      
<log loggingLevel="TRACE" message="Request from source: Header: ${headers}" />
<to uri="restlet:<--Consumed URL-->?restletMethod=POST" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code is trying to either -

1. Send in a `POST` request without the `{"name":"your name","phonenumber":"111-111"}`JSON body. In this case, you might wanna revisit your code and verify if you're setting the body correctly, like the `<setBody>` is properly used inside the `<to>` and `<from>` tags.
2. Send in a `POST` request to a URL which doesn't *accept* a `JSON` body. Have you tried adding `"Accept", "application/json"` as a header?
3. Verify if you don't have your `<from>` and `<to>` addresses mixed up (you mentioned "Consumed URL" which semantically should be "Consuming URL" in case of a `<to>` endpoint)

Comment: 1. I am able to print the body just before I call the POST request. But do I have any validator o check if the body is a valid JSON?

2. I have tried adding appliccation/json as content type as well as accept I have had no luck.